# artifactory 404 artifact not found

Tags: python, curl, deployment, artifactory

I'm using curl to deploy an artifact to a repository and on the initial PUT the artifact successfully gets deployed to the repo.  When I try to PUT the same artifact to the same repo I get a 404 "Could not locate artifact".  If I go through the UI I can deploy the same artifact to the same repo and everything works.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: curl --request PUT 'https://<artifactory-server>/artifatory/images/test.py' --data @test.py

Answer (score 20):

This can happen in a situation when:

1. The user you are using for deployment lacks delete permissions for the target repository
2. Artifactory is configured to ["Hide existence of unauthorized resources"](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+Security#ConfiguringSecurity-HideExistenceofUnauthorizedResources) (Admin->Security->General)

In such a case, for the first deployment the user has all the required permissions (deploy) and therefore the initial deployment succeeds.
For the second deployment, the user needs delete [permissions](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Managing+Permissions) in order to override the existing artifact. This would normally fail with a 403 status and the following message: `"Not enough permissions to overwrite artifact"`. However, when "Hide existence of unauthorized resources" is checked you get will get a 404 since the deployment operation is unauthorized.

Granting the deploying user delete permission on the target repository should solve this problem (Admin->Security->Permissions).

Comment: Thanks, the 1st is the problem I met.